# Can't Change Screen Brightness on Fedora on iMac

Tags: fedora, macintosh, brightness

I installed Fedora Linux 35 on my [iMac](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP576?locale=en_US)(21.5", Late 2009). It is working fine except that I can't control screen brightness neither through my keyboard(Apple's own keyboard) shortcuts nor the slider within Fedora itself. I can see the visual cue for the change in the screen but the actual brightness doesn't change.

Here is some info about my system.

`uname -r`:

```
5.16.15-201.fc35.x86_64
```

`lspci`:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 18)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor PCI Express x16 Root Port (rev 18)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB Universal Host Controller (rev 06)
00:1a.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller (rev 06)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset High Definition Audio (rev 06)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev 06)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev 06)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev 06)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB Universal Host Controller (rev 06)
00:1d.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller (rev 06)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge (rev a6)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation P55 Chipset LPC Interface Controller (rev 06)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset 6 port SATA AHCI Controller (rev 06)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset SMBus Controller (rev 06)
00:1f.6 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset Thermal Subsystem (rev 06)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RV730/M96-XT [Mobility Radeon HD 4670]
01:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RV710/730 HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 4000 series]
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries NetXtreme BCM5764M Gigabit Ethernet PCIe (rev 10)
03:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR928X Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) (rev 01)
04:00.0 PCI bridge: Texas Instruments XIO2213A/B/XIO2221 PCI Express to PCI Bridge [Cheetah Express] (rev 01)
05:00.0 FireWire (IEEE 1394): Texas Instruments XIO2213A/B/XIO2221 IEEE-1394b OHCI Controller [Cheetah Express] (rev 01)
ff:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QuickPath Architecture Generic Non-core Registers (rev 05)
ff:00.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QuickPath Architecture System Address Decoder (rev 05)
ff:02.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QPI Link 0 (rev 05)
ff:02.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 1st Generation Core i3/5/7 Processor QPI Physical 0 (rev 05)
ff:02.2 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 1st Generation Core i3/5/7 Processor Reserved (rev 05)
ff:02.3 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 1st Generation Core i3/5/7 Processor Reserved (rev 05)
```

`xrandr`:

```
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 1920 x 1080, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 1920 x 1080
default connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1920x1080     77.00*
```

Many others also had similar problems. Some say it's a kernel issue where others provide solutions. I tried a few of those solutions like [this](https://jamielinux.com/blog/cannot-adjust-screen-brightness-on-fedora/) one but no avail.

Any ideas?

Comment: There must be some files in `/sys` which you could write to to achieve what you're looking for. Check this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/149054/how-to-change-lcd-brightness-from-command-line-or-via-script

Comment: I forgot to mention that in the question. Already tried that and didn't work. Just like the on-screen slider, the value changes but has no effect.

Comment: Report here or look for already existing bug reports: https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/drm/amd/-/issues Given the age of your device I wouldn't expect any help though. AMD developers are busy working on current gen products and your device is probably used with Linux by all 10 people in the world.

Comment: For the interested, there is a discussion going on [here](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/drm/amd/-/issues/1958) related to this issue.

Comment: Thank you for the bug report! Really appreciate it. Most Linux users never bother however doing that actually helps Linux tremendously. Amazing a developer was instantly on it and helped debugging! Kinda unbelievable. I feel proud for myself.